# Playing audio sound everytime an element is pushed in array

Tags: javascript, algorithm, primes

I have a function called `primeFactors` where I try to find all the numbers that are divisors of a certain `n` number, but at the same time, they also have to be primes. Just a basic algorithm in a sense.

While doing that, I also thought it would be fun (just for the sake of it) to put audio sound that plays every time the `while` statement loops through the block. However, the sound plays only once, even though sometimes the result is an array of 3 factors (e.g. `[2, 7, 11]`). In this case, I would like the sound to play three times, before the pushing of each element into the array. Here's my code:

```
function primeFact(n) {
    let factors = [];
    let divisor = 2;
    let clap = new Audio('clap.mp3');

    while (n > 2) {
        if (n % divisor == 0) {
            clap.currentTime = 0;
            clap.play();
            factors.push(divisor);
            n = n / divisor;
        } else {
            divisor++;
        }
    }
    return factors;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to wait for it to finish playing before playing it the second time?

Comment: @SLaks Yes, that would be good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a queue. The sound is only playing one because in that loop it's almost instantaneous. This works:

```
<script>
var sounds = new Array,
    clap = new Audio('clap.mp3'); // no need to assign it every time
function primeFact(n) {
    let factors = [];
    let divisor = 2;

    while (n > 2) {
        if (n % divisor == 0) {
            clap.currentTime = 0;
            sounds.push(clap); // add sound to queue
            factors.push(divisor);
            n = n / divisor;
        } else {
            divisor++;
        }
    }
    playQueuedSounds(); // play all sounds added
    return factors;
}
function playQueuedSounds() {
    if (sounds.length === 0) return;
    var sound = sounds.pop(); // get last sound and remove it
    sound.play();
    sound.onended = function() { // go look at the queue again once current sound is finished
        playQueuedSounds();
    };
}
primeFact(25); // two clap noises :)
</script>
```